# Efficiently Handle Barcode Issues for Unreadable or Missing Barcodes in a Stationery Retail Shop?

Tags: time-management, artificial-intelligence, performance-analysis, image-recognition, barcode

My brother runs a retail stationery shop with well-trained stuff, and they've been facing challenges with unreadable or missing barcodes on certain low-cost stationery items like pencils and pens. This often leads to delays and frustrated customers at the checkout counter.

To address this issue, I've considered printing barcodes for each problematic item, sticking this barcode to the item and keeping all of them near the counter for quick access. However, I'm also looking for software solutions or additional suggestions to streamline this process further, for example: an AI driven or a camera recognition software which performs quickly and shows the correct barcode of the faulty item.

The final goal is to establish a reliable backup plan for cases where a barcode cannot be read or missing, avoiding the need for manual data entry or switching to a different barcode scanner. What are some effective backup plans or strategies that can be put in place to ensure a smooth checkout experience for customers?

Any software insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. The goal is to boost productivity and enhance customer satisfaction while handling these barcode-related challenges in the stationery retail business.

**P.S:** if this is not the right place to ask this question, kindly comment with the appropriate place where to ask it, I'm not looking for any specific software or tools that can help us efficiently generate barcodes for items without barcodes or unreadable barcodes, and how can we integrate them with our existing POS system.